# Checking Recaptcha still sends a message if false

Tags: javascript

There was a problem connecting Google Recaptcha v2. Or rather with the form. The check works fine, the error message displays, but, the message is still sent.

How can I fix this?

This is a form of feedback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#fast-call_submit").bind("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $('#feedback_form');
    var fields = form.serialize();
    $.ajax({
      url: form.attr('action') + '.json',
      type: 'post',
      data: fields,
      dataType: 'json',
      complete: function() {},
      success: function(response) {
        var v = grecaptcha.getResponse();
        if (v.length == 0) {
          $('.w-form-re-fail').show();
          return false;
        } else {
          if (response.status == 'ok') {
            $('.w-form-done').show();
            $('.w-form-fail').hide();
            form.hide();
          } else {
            $('.w-form-fail').show();
          }
          $('.w-form-re-fail').hide();
          return true;
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```